# c3 chart data label overlap issue

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I am using C3.js to create a line chart with data labels.

the problem is that some labels overlap when data from 2 lines are very close to each other.

Is there any way to fix this data overlapping issue in C3

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        labels:true,
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 230],
            ['data2', 40, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220],
            ['data3', 20, 200, 160, 400, 250, 250]
        ]
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e60o24d0/238/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in way to do so.
But you can try to identify and shift problematic labels in ***labels format function***:

```
labels: {
    format: function(v, id, point, line) {
        if (point === undefined || line === undefined) return;

        var label = d3
            .selectAll('.c3-chart-text')
            .selectAll('.c3-text')[line][point];

        if (...) { // set your condition
            var shift = ...; // set your calculation
            d3.select(label)
                .style('transform', 'translateY(' + shift + 'px)');
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Some inspiration can be found in [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7m9jvzx/1/).

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer don't forget to update c3js to latest version